# Select a subset of stocks using genetic algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I want to select 10 stocks out of the a possible set of given stocks that should be given some weight while the rest should be given zero weight. I have read the covariance matrix and returns from a file. My code is

```
Aeq = ones(1,stocks);
beq = 1;
lb = zeros(1,stocks);
up = ones(1,stocks);

options = gaoptimset;
options = gaoptimset(options,'PopulationSize' ,10);
fitnessFunction = @(x) (x * covariance * x') - (x * returns);

W = ga(fitnessFunction,stocks,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,up,[],options);
```

This code is giving weights to all the stocks. I cannot figure it out how to limit the number to 10.

Answer (score 0):

The `'PopulationSize'` parameters specifies how many entities - in your case portfolios - exist at each epoch, it has nothing to do with the weights assigned to each asset.

You need to write appropriate `crossoverFcn` and `mutationFcn` functions that explicitly include maintaining exactly 10 non-zero weights.

Comment: So can you give me an idea, what constraint to add in that case ?

Comment: You need to write appropriate functions, with the code in those functions enforcing your (cardinality) constaint.  It's not a case of adding additional constraints like A, b, Aeq, beq, etc, through the calling syntax to `ga`.